# Isn't [query-optimization] for NoSQL too?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, meta-tags

I noticed that [query-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization)'s tag wiki says that it's about SQL optimization, but there are already some NoSQL questions which use it. What should we do about it?

1. Retag NoSQL questions. How should we name the new tag? Can we prevent that NoSQL questions are tagged with [query-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) again?
2. Generalize [query-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization)'s tag wiki. Doesn't that make it a meta-tag?

---

NoSQL questions:

- [MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization+mongodb): 22 questions
- [Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization+hadoop): 6 questions
- [neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization+neo4j): 3 questions

(Experimental: [Search results without a SQL tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization+-sql+-postgresql+-postgresql-9.3+-oracle+-mysql+-h2+-sql-server+-sql-server-2008+-sql-server-2008-r2+-sql-server-2012+-sql-server-2014))

Comment: Are you asking just about non-SQL database query languages?  Or query languages in general?  We do have more general tags like [optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optimization).  So it isn't like there couldn't be another home.

Comment: @JasonMArcher: I only asked about database queries, because there are already many NoSQL questions tagged with it. I didn't check other query languages.

Comment: @JasonMArcher: Probably retagging NoSQL questions with [optimization] is the better option. But [query-optimization] would better be named [sql-optimization].