# Only SQL queries need [query-optimization]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [query-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) tag wiki excerpt says:

> The tag refers to how to make SQL queries run faster.

However, there are questions tagged with this tag and related to other query languages, e. g. [Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization+cypher).

My question is:

- Should the [query-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) tag be removed from not SQL related questions, *and / or*
- Should the [query-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) tag info be edited?

**Update 1**

Well, it seems that removing this tag from not SQL related questions is not an option. *As of 2018*, there are too many such questions.

Removing SQL from the tag info is also not an option, because there exist questions without additional clarifying tags (i. e. SQL is assumed).

I'd propose to edit tag info, but emphasize that SQL is assumed "by default" (i. e. when no other tags supplied).

**Update 2**

Tag wiki excerpt was [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5817319/revisions).

Comment: Looks a bit like a meta tag to me.

Comment: Ehm, there already was https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276885/isnt-query-optimization-for-nosql-too

Comment: I think the tag should be edited. If you want to look specifically for SQL query optimization, you can use a combination of tags, but it makes sense to me that this tag can be used for nonSQL queries too.